How to enforce Pull Requests before pushing but disable this ruleset during CI?
Given a public repository with a strong restriction. The ruleset requires pull requests before pushing to the main branch. Even the repository owner is not able to bypass these rules.
Given a release workflow that should bump the app's version number and push it (skipping CI) by using a personal access token
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'main'

jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          token: ${{ secrets.ADMIN_TOKEN }}

      - name: Get next version
        id: get_next_version
        uses: thenativeweb/get-next-version@2.6.3

      - name: Setup Git user
        if: ${{ steps.get_next_version.outputs.hasNextVersion == 'true' }}
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"
          git config --global user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"

      - name: Modify files, e.g. bumping package version etc.
        if: ${{ steps.get_next_version.outputs.hasNextVersion == 'true' }}
        run: |
          echo ${{ github.run_id }} > ${{ github.run_id }}.txt
          git add .
          git commit -m "chore: bump package version to ${{steps.get_next_version.outputs.version}} [skip ci]"
          git push

      - name: Create new tag
        if: ${{ steps.get_next_version.outputs.hasNextVersion == 'true' }}
        run: |
          git tag ${{steps.get_next_version.outputs.version}}
          git push origin ${{steps.get_next_version.outputs.version}}

I would like to get rid of the personal access token since it's my personal secret.

AFAIK it's not possible to authorize the Github bot user to bypass the ruleset => https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25305

I also tried using deployment keys but you get all the drawbacks as mentioned in the comments => https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/25305#discussioncomment-10728028


How did you solve the problem?

Personally, I like to keep version changes as separate branches and pull requests. There are many ways to solve for this but my favorite is https://github.com/changesets/changesets and they have a GitHub app: https://github.com/apps/changeset-bot.

so you bump the version via PR? As two separate steps? This might lead to wrong versioning if one deletes the version-change-pr , no?

The changesets package I linked handles what you mentioned seamlessly. Instead of providing a specific number, you instead provide a type of change: MAJOR, MINOR, or PATCH and the changesets action increments whatever the version is at the time of merge using the provided type. So if you have two release PRs, one with MAJOR and one with MINOR, it doesn't matter which one gets merged first because each of them only contain information of how to apply the version increase, not a specific version itself. In the case of deleting a release PR, no versions are skipped or missed with this setup.

thanks for your reply. I already have an action to calculate the next semantic version. So changesets provides "something" ( action, bot application, ... ) to bypass the ruleset?
